# AIX: lqueryvg documentation .. missing?

Tags: aix, man

I want some info about lqueryvg.

```
man lqueryvg
Manual entry for lqueryvg not found or not installed.
```

On the net I cannot found all options explained; some options are 
unknown.
Does someone know the missing options?

```
lqueryvg -A     #?
lqueryvg -a     #?
lqueryvg -c     #?
lqueryvg -D     #?
lqueryvg -F     #?
lqueryvg -g     #specify VGid
lqueryvg -L     #?
lqueryvg -N     #?
lqueryvg -n     #?
lqueryvg -P     #show pvs of disk
lqueryvg -p     #specify disk,disk0 for example
lqueryvg -s     #?
lqueryvg -t     #?
lqueryvg -v     #verbose
lqueryvg -Z     #?
lqueryvg -z     #?
```

Comment: Is perfect,I was out for working :) Now I return and vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appendix B.22 of the [AIX Logical Volume Manager from A to Z: Troubleshooting and Commands](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg245433.pdf) from the year 2000 describes the following:

> ```
> lqueryvg - An object file command that queries the attributes of a volume group.
> Usage: lqueryvg [-g VGID] [-p PVname] [-N] [-s] [-F] [-n] [-c] [-D] [-a] [-l] [-P] [-A] [-v] [-t]
>
> -g VGID The VGID of the volume group to query.
> -p PVname The name of the physical volume that contains the VGID.
> -N Returns the maximum number of logical volumes allowed in the volume group.
> -s Returns the physical partition size.
> -F Returns the number of free physical partitions in the volume group.
> -n Returns the current number of logical volumes in the volume group.
> -c Returns the current number of physical volumes in the volume group.
> -D Returns the total number of VGDAs for the volume group.
> -a Returns all the static attributes for the volume group ( ).
> -l Returns each LVID, logical volume name and state for each logical volume in the volume group.
> -P Returns each PVID, number of VGDAs and state for each physical volume in the volume group.
> -A Returns all attributes for the volume group (static attributes, logical volume details and physical volume details).
> -v Used only with the -p PVName flag to return the VGID from that physical volume.
> -t Includes the tags with the output for the above options.
> ```

There's also a note near the end of section 2.6.7 saying:

> Essentially, the low-level commands prefixed with l simply act as parsers
> and front-ends onto the LVM API calls. To gain a good understanding of
> these commands’ capabilities, one may look up the relevant API call, for
> example, lvm_queryvgs for lqueryvgs. These calls are listed in the AIX
> Version 4.3 Technical Reference: Kernel and Subsystems Technical
> Reference, Volume 1, SC23-4163. Recall, however, that BigVG
> functionality will not be documented by IBM.

which could land you at the [IBM® Knowledge Center for the lvm_queryvg Subroutine](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.basetrf1/lvm_queryvg.htm).

Comment: That redbook was my bible for so long.